# How to flush and verify an active directory group change?

Tags: active-directory

Is there a DOS command I can run on my client PC to fetch a new group assignment?  I'm logged in as the user.  I just added a security group to "Member Of" on the primary AD server.

Can I pull this information immediately?

Is there a way on the client to list the groups so I can verify the change?

I prefer the most compatible way, I'm using XP for the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Log off and log back on. That will update your user token. `whoami / groups` and `klist.exe` will both show you the membership and tickets assigned to the logged in user.

[This TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783557(WS.10).aspx) goes into more detail.

> If you add a user to a group after the user’s access token has been issued, or modify privileges assigned to the user account, the user must log off and then log on again before the access token will be updated.

Answer (score -1):

You can use:
**net user username /domain**

Comment: `net user` doesn't show nested groups and doesn't show universal groups in certain circumstances. It also doesn't update the current token, it would just list the membership.